# The Human Factor - Unintentional Exposure of Confidential Information in Forms

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

If one maintains an active persona on the clearnet and inadvertently enters a couple of words that are associated with that persona on an untrusted darknet form but deletes those identifying words without submitting the form, did the person just identify him/herself?

This is interesting to me as HTML forms could be abused in this way to capture information regardless if the user intends to submit a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have JavaScript enabled in Tor Browser then yes, the website can see any content you type into text boxes, even before you submit the form.